# Why is MYSQL table not showing?

Tags: mysql

I am practicing making Databases and tables, so I made a database for baseball info containing a table for Teams and Region they are from (not listed to accuracy). The teams show fine, but when I execute command `SELECT * FROM region`, it shows me all the columns of `ID, name, region`, but only has a null value. Code below:

```
CREATE DATABASE baseball;
USE baseball;
CREATE TABLE teams(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE region (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    region_name VARCHAR(255),
    teams_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (teams_id) REFERENCES teams(id)
);

INSERT INTO teams (name)
VALUES ('Yankees'), ('Red Sox'), ('Mets');

SELECT * FROM teams;

INSERT INTO region (region_name, teams_id)
VALUES ('NorthEast', 1),
        ('Northeast', 2),
        ('Central', 3),
        ('West', 4);

SELECT * FROM region;
```

Also, the names of teams repeat as well the more I mess with it, something is redundant about this. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't make the team names unique. So if you repeat the `INSERT INTO teams` query, you'll get duplicate teams.

Comment: You only created 3 teams, but in `region` you have `teams_id` going up to `4`. So the `INSERT INTO region` query is failing and nothing gets inserted.

Comment: I recommend you use some client that shows you errors, since you seem to not be aware of them.   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e4b8209dbbd525813536d79e0a9274bf

Comment: Do not use immediate value for a column which stored the relational value. You cannot predict the value which will be assigned by autoincrement with 100% accuracy. Use INSERT .. SELECT.